# cproj function is not working as intended

Tags: c

I have the following C test program, which makes use of the `cproj` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main(void)
{
    complex double z = cproj(INFINITY + NAN * I);
    printf("re=%f\nim=%f", creal(z), cimag(z));
}
```

*Note: I tried using `CMPLX(INFINITY, NAN)` instead of `INFINITY + NAN * I`, but MinGW doesn't seem to define it, even in C17 mode.*

The output of the program is:

```
re=1.#QNAN0
im=1.#QNAN0
```

However, according to N2176 7.3.9.5 (and N1570 7.3.9.5, and N1256 7.3.9.4, I don't have the real ISO C standard, only drafts), this is not correct behaviour:

> **7.3.9.5 The cproj functions**
>
> 2. The **cproj** functions compute a projection of z onto the Riemann sphere: z projects to z except that all complex infinities (even those
>    with one infinite part and one NaN part) project to positive infinity
>    on the real axis. If z has an infinite part, then **cproj**(z) is
>    equivalent to **`INFINITY + I * copysign(0.0, cimag(z))`**.

The variable `z` has one infinite part and one NaN part, yet the function returns two NaN parts, instead of infinity for the real part. Why is that?

Comment: I think it is a problem of `creal` rather than `cproj`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Using `((double*)(&z))[0]` returns NaN as well. Not sure if the cast is technically UB or not, but it should work, since complex numbers are required to be arrays of 2 floating points.

Comment: I don't think the problem is `cproj` but what you're passing in. My man page says (of initializing complex numbers using `a + b * I`): "certain complex values cannot be initialized using this technique, because I is actually a complex value." Since you don't have `CMPLX` available, maybe you could just create your own and use that? e.g.`#define MY_CMPLX(x, y) ((double complex){ x, y })`

Comment: That initializer is not valid in C but I get your point. It worked.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to resolve. Not that it matters, but I am curious what's wrong with the macro I posted. I tested and receive no warnings even compiling with `-Wall` and `std=c89`.

Comment: @EdmCoff C89 doesn't support complex numbers at all. Are you using compiler extensions?

Comment: I assume my complex.h file happens to work with c89 even through it's not required by the standard. I was only experimenting with c89 to see if that explained why you said it wasn't valid. At any rate, on Clang on my system there doesn't appear to be any difference between my `((double complex){ x, y })` and your `*(complex double*)(double[2]){ x, y }`.

Comment: On GCC (MinGW), `((double complex){ 3, 4 })` will create the complex number 3.0+0.0i and throw `warning: excess elements in scalar initializer`. Basically, it takes 3 to be the whole complex numbers and it treats the rest as excess. AFAIK complex types don't support aggregate initialization, so this behavior makes sense.

Comment: Also, please note that in C89, compound literals such as `((int){ 3 })` are not allowed. You must truly be using a lot of compiler extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as pointed out by @EdmCoff, is not with `cproj`, but with the initialization of the variable, `INFINITY + NAN * I`. This example shows it:

```
complex double z = INFINITY + NAN * I;
printf("re=%f\nim=%f", creal(z), cimag(z));
```

Output:

```
re=1.#QNAN0
im=1.#QNAN0
```

The variable is initialized incorrectly even without using `cproj`.

If the `CMPLX` macro is available (which it should be, on any C11/C17 implementation which claims to implement complex arithmetic, but for some reason on MinGW it's not), it should fix things:

```
complex double z = CMPLX(INFINITY, NAN);
printf("re=%f\nim=%f", creal(z), cimag(z));
```

If the macro is not available, a portable, conformant way to initialize the number is:

```
complex double z;
memcpy(&z, (double[2]){ INFINITY, NAN }, sizeof z);
printf("re=%f\nim=%f", creal(z), cimag(z));
```

Or, without using `memcpy`:

```
complex double z = *(complex double*)(double[2]){ INFINITY, NAN };
printf("re=%f\nim=%f", creal(z), cimag(z));
```

Output:

```
re=1.#INF00
im=1.#QNAN0
```